# How to get the full path of the directories with the same name as some files?

Tags: c#, directory

I've got some text files in one path and I want to find folders with the name of the text files in a different path and if they exist get their full path to a variable. I've done something like this

```
var files=Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\C#\Sample files","*.txt",SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach (var file in files)
{
    var filename=Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    var folderFound = Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\data", filename, SearchOption.AllDirectories).First();
    Console.WriteLine(folderFound);             
}
```

But the problem here is when there isn't a folder found with that name the program throws an exception...how do I sort this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `First()` on your result, which throws if there are no results.

Call `FirstOrDefault()` instead, which will return `null` if there are no entries, which you can check for before calling `Console.WriteLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove `First()` 
and check if there are any results

you can do it with

```
  if (folderFound.Any())
      Console.WriteLine(folderFound);
```

Comment: I think in your example it would be `Console.WriteLine(folderFound.First())`, which would involve two enumerations of (the now badly named) `folderFound`